# Most users can access my site but many others cant

Tags: vps

this problem is driving me crazy. In the latest days, some of my users report they cant access my site. They get a server not found error page. However, many others including myself can access it normally without any problem. Why? I have asked my web host, my domain manager, etc. and nobody seems to know whats the problem.

Is it a problem with my server? I run a VPS. Is it a problem with my domain? Or i am being just hacked? If only 2 or 3 users had this problem i wouldnt care that much, but its quite a number so im concerned. I have asked way too many people, i have searched the web, asked in forums but nobody knows the answer. Please help.

Thank you.

This is my domain name (please look at the picture)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HGha.jpg

Comment: It sounds like it's potentially a DNS issue. If you can share the URL, people here can look deeper.

Comment: So my host is the problem? Because they assure me they cant do anything on their side but i need to know exactly what the problem si and some proof so i can demand them to fix this.

Comment: DNS seems to be fine for that domain from what I see.. If I was in your shoes, I'd try to get someone that's experiencing the issue to try manual DNS lookups and traceroutes on their computer they're having the issue with.

Comment: Do you have a specific example of a user that cannot reach your site? Have any changes been made in the past week? Are the users clicking on a known good  link or attempting to enter your domain name, which has a high probability of user error? If the latter, have they sent you browser screenshots? [DNS results appear to be consistent](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.saintseiyaforos.net), so that is unlikely to be your problem unless the IP address has changed recently and some users have stale results cached.

Comment: no, nothing has changed that i know of. The problem is that the users who experience this problem are not computer proficient so its a little complicated to have them provide a more specific explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen issues like this before and it can be hard to diagnose.

To be sure your DNS is ok run one of the many only DNS check tools available online such as mxtoolbox or pingdom.com

What you really need is to be sitting at a computer where the problem is occurring.  Or remoted in via teamviewer or similar tool.  You might be able to persuade someone who is having the issue to remote into their PC to run some diagnostics. Or just ask a slightly more tech savy individual to do the diagnostics for you.  They can watch what you are doing.

I'd run these diagnostic tests in this order.  I've seen issues with all 3 of them.  Often it was a problem with one particular ISP or router or a misconfiguration.  But misconfiguration usually affect everyone not just some people.

On a machine where it's occurring (if this is possible).

1. Check if the DNS is providing you with the correct answer.

   Very often a cause of problems.  But usually if affects everyone not just a select few.  Still worth looking into though.
2. Then run a trace route.

   I've seen it were we couldn't deliver email to a particular company and it turned out to be a routing issue.  It eventually got resolved we we started identifying where it was breaking and contacting a few people.
3. Ping the host using successively larger packet sizes.

   This sounds rather weird and it is. We had an issue where the largest ISP in my country were doing something weird with MTU or there was a problem possibly with the cheap routers they were giving out to their customers. Somehow we worked out that dropping the MTU on the server down to 500 bytes and all the customers that were having issues could suddenly connect. I think the problem resolved itself once we started seeing a pattern and identified that the customers were from a particular ISP and we started making noise to them.

Comment: Sorry, how should i do number 1?

Comment: on windows run nslookup [sitename]

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check would be DNS, any apache site configurations and also permissions on any .htaccess files you may have. An interesting point is that when I visited your site, the first attempt at loading failed and brought up a download box for the file itself, saying the stream was application/octet. You might check the default encoding of your served files, as well.

Comment: You mean you were prompted to download my index.php file?

Comment: It was a blank filename, so I'm not sure exactly what was going on there, but it definitely shouldn't be being served as an application/octet stream if it's just a PHP file.

Comment: Another thing you might check if you have URL Rewriting enabled is your URL rewrite rules.

Comment: That was only the first time? What about now?

Comment: Yes, just the first time I tried to load the page. When I refreshed, it loaded with no issue.

Comment: Maybe it was a temporary setback or something. My users claim no matter how many times they reload the page, they cant see it.